# MousePosition Scaling over a cell

Tags: options

I'm trying to have the button follow the mouse while within the output text cell. The scaling does not exactly work as intended (fails to follow mouse correctly).

```
Dynamic[Overlay[{txtO, 
   Button[Style["Button", Blue, Italic, 15], Print[1]]}, All, 2, 
  Alignment -> 
   Rescale[MousePosition["CellContentsScaled", {0, 0}], {0, 1}, {-1, 
     1}]]]
```

Additionally, how would I make the button 1) Snap to 0,0 when the mouse is not over the output text cell anymore; and 2) disappear completely when not within the boundaries of the text cell.

The Rescale for {0,1} -> {-1,1} helped a little, but it seems I am not using CellContentsScaled correctly, as the documentation says it should range from 0 to 1 over the cell only (occasional negative numbers pop up, and values are present with the mouse outside the cell)

Comment: I don't see much happening when I float my mouse in the neighborhood of the button. Perhaps the undefined txt0 has something to do with it?

Comment: Whoops sorry there, txt0 was a random paragraph of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that "CellContentsScaled" doesn't relate to the *size of the cell's content*. Instead it relates to the size of the *cell content area*, i.e., the space within the displayed cell that potentially could contain something, which may be bigger than the size of the actual content.

A brute-force work-around (there should be better ways to do this):

```
stuffSize = 
   Overlay[{"mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm", 
           Button[Style["Button", Blue, Italic, 15], Print[1]]}, All, 2, 
           Alignment -> {0, 0}
   ] // Rasterize // ImageDimensions;

 Dynamic[
    Overlay[{"mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm", 
              Button[Style["Button", Blue, Italic, 15], Print[1]]
            }, All, 2, 
            Alignment -> 
                (-1 + 2 MousePosition["CellContentsAbsolute", {0, 0}]/stuffSize), 
            Background -> LightBlue
   ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]